# Time value getting beyond 60 min android

Tags: android, android-calendar, android-timer

getting the wrong end time value (goes beyond to 60mins)

I am working on the calendar view. When I click an empty view I need to get the start time and end time I am getting start time properly but end time is going beyond 60 minutes

Eg: 4:69pm, 4:79pm

I need as 5:09pm, 5:19pm

Please check my code, when I add 60 minutes, it is going beyond 60 minutes

```
mWeekView.setEmptyViewClickListener(new
 WeekView.EmptyViewClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onEmptyViewClicked(Calendar time) {

         String startTime = String.format("%02d:%02d",time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),time.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
         String endtime   = String.format("%02d:%02d",time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),60+time.get(Calendar.MINUTE));/*time.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000*/
         String startdate = String.format("%d/%s/%s",time.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),time.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1,time.get(Calendar.YEAR));


         Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),AddAppointment.class);
         intent.putExtra("daystartdate", startdate);
         intent.putExtra("daystartTime",startTime);
         intent.putExtra("dayendtime",endtime);
         startActivity(intent);
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you want to add an hour to the current `Calendar` object, so you will need to create a new calendar object and add the time you want to it or you can use the already passed `time` object. For example,

```
mWeekView.setEmptyViewClickListener(new
 WeekView.EmptyViewClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onEmptyViewClicked(Calendar time) {

         String startTime = String.format("%02d:%02d",time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),time.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
         time.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
         String startdate = String.format("%d/%s/%s",time.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),time.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1,time.get(Calendar.YEAR));
         time.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
         time.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 60);
         String endtime   = String.format("%02d:%02d",time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),time.get(Calendar.MINUTE));/*time.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000*/


         Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),AddAppointment.class);
         intent.putExtra("daystartdate", startdate);
         intent.putExtra("daystartTime",startTime);
         intent.putExtra("dayendtime",endtime);
         startActivity(intent);
     }
 });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Almost correct. You need to obtain your `startDate` before you add `60` minutes as that might change it.

Comment: and instead of use `+1` month use `add(Calendar.Month , 1)`  method because if month is equal to 12 result will be 13 ;)

Comment: what is this `+1` anyways :D ? I guess the variable naming is all twisted in the question

Comment: `time.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1` in startdate

Comment: Yea I know where it is, just wondering what's the purpose of it

Answer (score 1):

For the solution you use the calendar Util methods

For the Start time you can use Calendar.setTime(Date date) methods.
and for end time you can use the same calender instance and add 60 minutes to it with method calender.add(int time, Calendar.Minutes);

It May help you.